# Saving Div Content As Image On Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have been learning a bit of jQuery and .Net in VB. I have created a product customize tool of sorts that basically layers up divs and add's text, images etc on top of a tshirt.

I'm stuck on an important stage!

I need to be able to convert the content of the div that wraps all these divs of text and images to one flat image taking into account any CSS that has been applied to it also.

I have heard of things that I could use to screen capture the content of a browser on the server which could be possible for low res thumbs etc, but it sounds a little troublesome! and it would really be nice to create an image of high res.

I have also heard to converting the html to html5 canvas then writing that out... but looks too complicated for me to fathom and browser support is an issue.

Is this possible in .NET?

Perhaps something with javascript could be done?

Any help or guidance in the correct direction would be appreciated!

EDIT:

I'm thinking perhaps I could do with two solutions for this. Ideally I would end up with a normal res jpg/png etc for displaying on the website, But also a print ready high res file would be very desirable as well.

PostScript Printer - I have heard of it but I'm struggling to find a good resource to understand it for a beginner (especially with wiki black out). Perhaps I could create a html page from my div content and send it to print to a EPS file. Anyone know any good tutorials for this?

Comment: Create a browser process server side, grab a screenshot from that, save the image. There are complete libraries for that. Threading can be a problem, but always better than clientside.

Comment: Thanks for your response @CasparKleijne. Are you able to recommend one?

Comment: Another possibility is to use a server-side tool to convert HTML markup to a scalable form like PDF, such as Prince or Flying Saucer. Of course there'll be some significant problems with resolution if image files are included; to me that'll be a big challenge.  For printing on a shirt, you want a pretty high DPI in order for it to look good.  Have you investigated what places like spreadshirt.com do?

Comment: Hi @Pointy. Yes have looked at spreadshirt. Very nice website. No idea what they are using! I have just read another article and perhaps printing out to a postscript printer to give a high res file would do it... Trouble is so many options! I want the easiest as Im a beginner and also the most reliable and the best at the same time! Not asking much am I!!! Thanks for your input, the idea of a PDF got me on the track of perhaps doing something better like generating a EPS file that is much better for going to  the printers with.

Comment: Eek. HTML isn't exactly intended as an image-generation tool. If you just need to build images (as opposed to generating a screenshot-like capture of a page), look at the System.Drawing namespace.

Comment: @DavidLively I'm using jQuery at the moment as I want it to display any changes made instantly on the browser without posting back. If I used system.drawing (which I thought was just for apps not web but i'm wrong!) could I display the changes using an update panel without full postback? Can I use it to layer up images, add text etc? Any good beginner tutorials you can point me to? Many thanks!

Comment: @user1147410 Ah - no, the .NET assemblies are only available server-side, so if you're looking to provide image editing capability on the client, you'll have to go another direction.

Comment: For the record, SpreadShirt is using flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did this... about 10 years ago.  Interestingly, the tech available really hasn't changed too much.

**update - Best Answer**

Spreadshirt licenses their product: http://blog.spreadshirt.net/uk/2007/11/27/everyones-a-designer-free-designers-for-premium-partners/

Just license it.  Don't do this yourself, unless you have real graphics manipulating and print production experience.  I'd say in today's world you're looking at somewhere around 4,000 to 5,000 hours of dev time to duplicate what they did... And that's if you have two top tier people working on it.

---

**Short answer: you can't do it in html.**

**Slightly longer answer**:
It doesn't work in part because you can't screen cap the client side and get the level of resolution needed for production type printing.  Modern screen resolution is usually on the order of 100 ppi.  For a decent print you really need something between 3 and 6 times that density.  Otherwise you'll have lots of pixelation and it will generally look like crap when it comes out.

**A different Answer:**
Your best bet is to leverage something like SVG (scalable vector graphics) and provide a type of drawing surface to the browser.  There are several ways of doing this using Flash (Spreadshirt.com uses this) or Silverlight (not recommended).  We used flash and it was pretty good.

You *might* be able to get away with using HTML 5.  Regardless, whatever path you pick is going to be complicated.

Once the user is happy with their drawing and wants to print it out, you create the final file and run a process to convert it to Postscript or whatever format your t-shirt provider needs.  The converter (aka RIP software) is going to either take a long time to develop or cost a bunch of money... pick one.  (helpful hint: buy it.  Back then, we spent around $20k US and it was far cheaper than trying to develop).

Of course, this ignores issues such as color matching and calibration.  This was actually our primary problem.  Everyone's monitor is slightly different and what looks like red on one machine is pink on another.

And for a little background, we were doing customized wrapping paper.  The user added text, selected images from our library or uploaded their own, and picked a pattern.  Our prints came out on large-format HP Inkjet printers (36" and 60" wide).  Ultimately we spent between $200k and $300k just on dev resources to make it happen... and it did, unfortunately, the price point we had to sell at was too high for the market.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you for your very full answer. We sell cotton bags, Lots of them! We have several screen printing machines, DTG, Wax transfer, flex etc also. At the moment anyone wanting a print has to request a quote via a form, phone etc. We accept print jobs from 1 to millions. No minimum at all. I have investigated purchasing a package they are around £2500 to £5000 which isn't a problem, but all of them are clunky in some way. I would like the freedom to evolve something like this, change the style, change the features, pricing structure etc. Keeping it simple then building on it.

Comment: @user1147410: I'd say call/email spreadshirt.  See if their stuff can be adapted to your use case.  They do seem geared to using their own fullfilment, but maybe you can leverage this as a partnership so that they can expand their own offering with some type of revenue share.  Might be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use some server-side tool, check [phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/). This is a headless webkit browser (with no gui) which can take a page's screenshot, an uses a javascript api. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Send the whole div with user generated content back to server using ajax call.
Generate an HTML Document on server using 'HtmlTextWriter' class.
Then you can convert that HTML file using external tools like

(1) http://www.officeconvert.com/products_website_to_image.htm#easyhtmlsnapshot

(2) http://html-to-image.acasystems.com/faq-html-to-picture.htm

which are not free tools, but you can use them by creating new Process on server.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will keep this in mind. I was hoping to find a way of doing this for free ideally.

Comment: There are free tools to convert html to postscript http://www.w3.org/Tools/html2things.html

Answer (score 0):

The best option I came across is [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). It comes with a tool called **wkhtmltoimage**. It uses QtWebKit (A Qt port of the WebKit rendering engine) to render a web page, and converts the result to PDF or image format of your choice, all done at server side.

Because it uses WebKit, it renders everything (images, css and even javascript) just like a modern browser does. In my use case, the results have been very satisfying and are almost identical to what browsers would render.

To start, you may want to look at how to run external tools in .NET:
[Execute an external EXE with C#.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065504/execute-an-external-exe-with-c-net)