# Execute an external EXE with C#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am executing a process in C# but I want to be able to do it without specifying the path.  Where can I place the executable within the project so that the code finds it wuthout specifying a path?

At the moment I have:

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = @"C:\Docs\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
```

Which runs fine but what I'd like to end up with is:

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "wkhtmltopdf.exe";
```

I've tried placing the EXE in a folder in the project, in the root of the project, in the `bin` folder of the project - all unsuccessfully.

Comment: It needs to be in the same directory as where your own .exe is - typically bin/debug/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "wkhtmltopdf.exe";  
psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
Process proc = Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\DevServer\\10.0"`

Comment: Are you running this code as website/webservice? If yes then try HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")

Comment: OK this worked - I wasn't running it as web code (it was just a C# class) but ultimately I want it to run as a web service anyway, so this is a good solution for me.  Sadly I don't have enough rep to upvote you otherwise I would - thanks.

Comment: You are able to select my answer as correct. And for future: please, mention details of project(that you code from service) directly in quesion

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing right now, but maybe this will be helfpul?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx

Just set this path to `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\DevServer\\10.0"`

Answer (score 0):

put the binary whenever you want and add this folder to the %PATH% variable of the system

Comment: I should have mentioned that ultimately I want to deploy this as a web service so I won't necessarily have access to the %PATH% variable.  Besides which, I also tried putting the EXE in C:\Windows\System32 and it still didn't find it...

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the [Enviroment.SpecialFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx).

Then you can infer a correct path without having to hardcode any values or having to request input from the user.